# Find the probability that $2$ black balls extracted are from urn $B$.

Tags: probability

> The urn $A$ contains $3$ black balls and $5$ red balls while urn $B$ contains
>   $4$ black balls and $7$ red balls , If the $2$ balls are extracted simultaneosuly
>    from any of the two urns are found to be black, find the probability that they are extracted from urn $B$.

$\dfrac{\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{8}{2}}+\dfrac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{11}{2}}=\dfrac{333}{1540}$

I am not sure if my logic is correct, also please tell that which concept of probability this 
question uses whether is is binomial distribution or condintional probability etc.

I look for a short and simple way .

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: Both balls are extracted only from a box?

Comment: $\ \ \ \ $ Yess.

Comment: Can you use total probability formula and conditional probability?

Comment: U mean am I allowed to use "total probability formula and conditional probability"?

Comment: Yes, i mean it.

Comment: Yes I can use any formula , method , no restriction on the process, this questions are generally objective type with options  ,I need to check an option and proceed.

Comment: Does "two balls are extracted simultaneously from any of the two urns" mean they may be extracted from different urns, or must be extracted from the same urn?  Is the urn selected first, or are the balls selected without bias?

Comment: @graham :They must be extracted from the same urn.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question, and that K. Jiang's answer is correct. To rephrase the question: _In the event that $2$ balls extracted from either urn, at random and without replacement, are both black, what is the probability that they were both extracted from urn $B$?_

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when you add probabilities. Usually, adding is fine if the probabilities are distinct (they do not affect each other), but here, they most certainly do. The method I will walk through in this solution requires knowledge of some basic [conditional probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

We begin by finding the total number of ways to end up with $2$ black balls. This is easy to count: we can select $2$ of the $3$ from $A,$ which can be done in $\dbinom{3}{2} = 3$ ways; $2$ of the $4$ from $B,$ which can be done in $\dbinom{4}{2} = 6$ ways; or $1$ ball from each urn, which can be done in $3 \cdot 4 = 12$ ways. Our "sample space" is $3 + 6 + 12 = 21$ ways (to get $2$ black balls).

Now we find the number of ways to get $6$ black balls from just $B.$ We already found this (above) to be $6$ ways.

Our probability, then, is $P = \frac{6}{21} = \boxed{\frac{2}{7}}.$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray}
P(B|bb)=P(bb|B)\frac{P(B)}{P(bb)}...(*)
\end{eqnarray}$

Now, $P(bb)=P(bb|B)P(B)+P(bb|A)P(A)=\frac{1}{2}(P(bb|B)+P(bb|A))=\frac{1}{2}\left[\dfrac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{11}{2}}+\dfrac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}\right]$.

Sustituying in $(*)$

$\begin{eqnarray}
P(B|bb)&=&P(bb|B)\frac{P(B)}{P(bb)}\\
&=&\dfrac{\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{11}{2}}}{\dfrac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{11}{2}}+\dfrac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}}\\
&=&\frac{56}{111}\\
&\sim&0.504
\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 1):

I will use some notation with which you might be unfamiliar. Feel free to ask for clarification.

Let $T = \{\text{Drew 2 black balls}\}$ and $U = \{\text{Chose urn $i$}\}$ for $i = A,B$. Then, we are interested in
$$P(U_B|T) = \frac{P(TU_B)}{P(T)}.\tag{$\star$}$$
This is true using [Bayes' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem).

Notice that it would make calculations easier if I conditioned the numerator on $U$
$$P(TU_B) = P(T|U_B)P(U_B)$$
Since the question doesn't specify, I think we can assume that each urn is chosen with equal probability, so $P(U_B) = \frac{1}{2}$.
Now, if we chose urn $U$, what is the probability that we draw two black balls?
You seem to understand that this is
$$P(T|U_B) = \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{11}{2}} = \frac{6}{55}.$$
To get the denominator in $(\star)$, we use the [law of total probability](https://www.google.com/search?q=total+probability&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and then condition again on $U_i$,
\begin{align*}
P(T) &= P(TU_A)+P(TU_B) \\
&= P(T|U_A)P(U_A)+P(T|U_B)P(U_B) \\
&= \frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{11}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{2} \\
&= \frac{3}{28}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{6}{55}\cdot\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
Putting it all together we see that
$$P(U_B|T) = \frac{P(TU_B)}{P(T)} = \frac{\frac{6}{55}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{28}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{6}{55}\cdot\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{56}{111}=0.5045045
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the balls must be extracted from the same urn, we simply wish the conditional probability that they are event $B$: "from urn-$B$", given that they are event $b$: "both black".

We use Bayes' Rule and the Law of Total Probability.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B\mid b) & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(b\mid B)\;\mathsf P(B)}{\mathsf P(b)} & \textsf{Bayes' Rule}
\\ & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(b\mid B)\,\mathsf P(B)}{\mathsf P(b\mid B)\;\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(b\mid A)\;\mathsf P(A)} & \text{Law of Total Probability}
\\ & = \frac{\mathsf P(b\mid B)}{\mathsf P(b\mid B)+\mathsf P(b\mid A)} & {\textsf{assuming no bias in urn selection}\\\mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(B) } \\ & = \dfrac{\binom 3 2 / \binom 8 2}{\binom 3 2 / \binom 8 2 + \binom 4 2 / \binom {11} 2} & \textsf{as you were attempting to reason} \\ & = \frac {55}{111}  \end{align}$$